# java compilation error when using reflection with templates

Tags: java, templates, reflection, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
private <D extends Object> void foo(D d) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    d = d.getClass().newInstance(); // Compilation error: "Incompatible types: Required D, Found: Object"
}
```

Why do I get this error?

To my understanding, the compiler knows that d is D type (which extends Object)...?

Comment: Because in Java everything but the primitives is an Object and the type of generics is erased during runtime, the compiler has no clue what class (which must be instantiated !) you are possibly meaning. String ? Number ? WUT ? Fix: Replace D simply by Object  => private Object void foo(Object d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
private <D extends Object> void foo(D d) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    d = d.getClass().cast(d.getClass().newInstance()); // Compilation error: "Incompatible types: Required D, Found: Object"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`javac` can't know what is `D`, it will be evaluated on runtime.
`D` is known by your compiler as `? extends Object`, so the type of `d.getClass()` is `Class<? extends Object>`, and so `newInstance()` returns an `Object`. As pointed out by Victor, you only need a cast here :)

On a side note, these kind of code is often write in this way:

```
private <D> void foo(Class<D> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  D d = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

So, `clazz` is a `Class<D>` and not a `Class<? extends Object>`, and `newInstance()` returns `D` and not `Object`.